# What's the integral of $\int \frac{1 - \cos kx }{1 - \cos x}dx$?

Tags: trigonometric-integrals

How do I evaluate $$\int \frac{1 - \cos kx }{1 - \cos x}dx$$?

I realise that $\cos kx$ can be expressed as a [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) but because it's part of a fraction I can't see that this helps very much.

Comment: I suppose that this would lead to hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside some nasty hypergeometric function it *seems* that
$$\large\color{blue}{f_k=\int \frac{1-\cos(kx)}{1-\cos(x)}\,dx=
kx+2 \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{k-n}n\, \sin(nx)}$$

You can easily check it using series expansion.

Comment: Really?  That's great!  Can you show me how you got there?

Comment: @EdGraham. Just looking at the very very first integrals. The pattern is clear. But notice that I wrote ***"it seems"***. I did not have time to make a proof.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's a guess.  Fair enough.

Comment: I have now verified this formula by differentiating both sides and am satisfied that it is correct.  Thank you!

Comment: The key identity to use is $\frac{1 - \cos kx}{1 - cos x} = k + 2\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n\cos (k-n)x$.  I was aware of this but didn't think to use it - oops!